# Where is Lebonnaire in Canada?

Tags: canada, place-names

I have a record that indicates a great aunt was born "at" (not "in") Lebonnaire, Canada. The record does not indicate which Province.

I know her father was Canadian, her mother was from New Jersey.   All siblings were born in USA, she was the only child they had who was born in Canada, so this is the only lead I have regarding her father, who was Firmen Vaillancourt.

Is Lebonnaire a town?  A hospital?  Or some other place?

I have been unable to locate it via Google search when searching for it different ways based on the information I have.

Comment: Hi Randy and welcome. Is the source record you are referring to this obituary in *The Blaine Journal* for Edith Loomis (d.1931)? http://wagenweb.org/whatcom/obits/obitli_ly.htm

Comment: Sounds like "Le Bon Air" (which isn't a place either).

Comment: Hi, Randy, welcome to G&FH.SE.  Could you tell us a little bit about the nature of the sources you have examined? What year did the family enter the US? If you can determine when and where the family came to the US, it might give you a clue about possible migration patterns.

Comment: A surname? https://www.google.com/search?q=Lebonnaire&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Lebonnaire+genealogy&filter=0

Comment: @JanMurphy The 1920 census states immigration date of 1862, so that suggests they came back to the US shortly after Edith's birth. Also, the 1910 census gives her birthplace as "Canada (Fr)", which indicates (unsurprisingly) that this place is likely in French Canada (i.e. area around Quebec).

Comment: @vervet Rather than trying to leap back from a marriage to a birth record, I would suggest going backwards chronologically -- ex. my family that passed through [Toronto](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9261/1006).  For the purposes of the question I arranged events chronologically going forward, but when constructing or filling in a timeline I try to work outward from known events in small steps rather than big leaps.

Comment: @JanMurphy Yes. No leaps made. Just trying to add helpful information as I am not sure if/when the OP will return to answer those questions. I found the obituary, then the 1930 census, then 1920 census, then 1910 census, etc. going back chronologically. However, for the purposes of this question (Where is Lebonnaire in Canada?) I thought it might be useful to include records that contain pertinent information about her Canadian origins?

Comment: Sounds like a maritime province name. I would search no further west than Quebec for this place.

Comment: @vervet I think we're in agreement with each other.  All I meant was that it's better to work backwards to 1862 in steps and you were doing that.

Comment: @JanMurphy   thanks all!, record is fr Blaine Journal.   I can trace Vaillancourt  from  time in New Jersey (Firmen Vaillancourt married Louise Powell) (which I don't think is spelled Louisa as I've   seen her gravestone in Reno, Nv, and her daughter, my gr-grand , was Iola Louise, not Louisa), they had a daughter in New Jersey, then my gr-aunt in Canada, then more daughters back in New Jersey.

Comment: .   I can trace them fwd, they moved to Lawrence, Ks & were there for at least 5 yrs, before move to Reno, Nv, where they had 1 daughter.   No cousins have info.   I'm trying to find info on Firmen Vaillancourt and/or Louise (nee Powell).  Powell was common in New Jersey, and Vaillancourt common Quebec.  Obit for Edith is the 1st reference I have re where in Canada my Vaillancourts came from.  The one census you mention indicates French Canada, but most ref show English, so open to either

Comment: With any US Federal Census record you find, check the [enumerator's instructions](https://usa.ipums.org/usa/voliii/tEnumInstr.shtml) at IPUMS USA -- every census has different instructions, so the information on one census is not automatically equivalent to the next.  See my answer to [What is “Canada E” in the 1860 US Federal Census?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9266/1006) especially the updated section at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I think the place you're looking for is in Quebec, possibly in the Témiscouata region. There have been many Vaillancourts in this area. For example, there are [two men named Féménin Vaillancourt in the 1861 census](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&db=1861Canada&h=794306723). One is listed as 29 years old (born approx. 1832) and the other 16 years old. They may be related to your Edith. Strangely, in the census image below it says that the woman, Briget White from Ireland, is not part of the family - even though she is in the spot usually held by the wife/mother.

[image]

There was also [50 acres granted to Jean-Bet Vaillancourt of Whitworth, Témiscouata](http://qfhs.ca/cstm_landGrant.php?page=1&nr=50&scl=snd&st=G&srch=vaillancourt), in 1852.

Drilling down further, there is [a beach called Bon Air in Packington Témiscouata, Quebec](http://www4.rncan.gc.ca/search-place-names/unique/ELMZB). There is also an interesting fellow named Benoît **Valcourt** mentioned in the [history of Packington](http://packington.org/historique). Perhaps Bon Air was a landmark or settlement before the official establishment of Packington.

I believe if you do some digging in these regions, you may find some ancestors of your great-aunt Edith.